# UE4 AI как научить открывать двери?

Tags: unreal-engine-4, искусственный-интеллект

Есть игра, там бот бегает за игроком(постоянно). Мне бы хотелось сделать двери, но если я сделаю двери, сразу возникает вопрос, как сделать чтобы бот их открывал... Ведь, бот, когда я захожу в комнату и закрываю двери, не стоит у двери, а уходит куда-то. У меня появилась идея, вычислять в игроке комнату, где он находится, но мне кажется этот способ не из лучших... Не могли бы вы подсказать способ по-лучше? Бот написан на `behavier tree`. А я новичок в `AI`, так что вообще понятия не имею, как это лучше сделать.

P.S. я не прошу сам код(хотя было бы не плохо, если бы вы и его скинули), я прошу хотя бы сам алгоритм, как это реализовать

Answer (score 0):

У меня была подобная проблема. Основная беда была в том, что если на пути стоит дверь, то AI считал её за стену, через которую пройти нельзя, поэтому даже не мог простроить путь через неё, пусть даже упираясь в стену. Адекватное решение этой проблемы я, увы, не нашел, но придумал специфичный обход. Я убрал физику у всех дверей, что позволило AI простроить пусть через эти двери внутрь комнат. Чтобы была возможность их открывать, я возвращал физику, когда игрок подходил к этой двери. Если же подходил бот, то дверь испарялась. Можно сделать, чтобы она открывалась при подходе. Что-то такое)

Comment: ахахахах, интересное решение, но мне кажется, что будет баг когда бот находится близко с игроком и они подходят к двери. Или если игрок стоит в комнате рядом с дверью - то бот не сможет пройти через дверь.

Comment: @Lofectr Возможно, да)
Я описал примерное решение, у меня вроде не было таких проблем потом. Так или иначе, это костыль, да)

Answer (score -1):

можешь по триггеру - когда бот заходит - дверь открылась, когда выходит - закрылась
можешь через linetrace проверять путь бота, и если на пути возникает дверь, то при определенном расстояние открывать ее